# InnerHtml won't show results with Angular

Tags: css, angular, innerhtml

I'm trying to build a weather app using angular and I'm trying to display icons according to the data received so I made this function that will return the icon according to the data:

```
  icon(icon: any) {
    switch (icon) {
      case 'rain' :
        return '<i class="icon-basecloud"></i><i class="icon-rainy"></i>';
        break;
      case 'cloudy' :
        return '<i class="icon-basecloud"></i><i class="icon-cloud"></i>';
        break;
      case 'partly-cloudy-day' :
        return '<i class="icon-sunny-cloud"></i><i class="icon-sunny-cloud-sunny"></i>';
        break;
      case 'partly-cloudy-night' :
        return '<i class="icon-basecloud"></i><i class="icon-night"></i>';
        break;
      case 'clear-day' :
        return '<i class="icon-day"></i>';
        break;
      case 'clear-night' :
        return '<i class="icon-night"></i>';
        break;
      default:
        return '<i class="icon-basecloud"></i><i class="icon-rainy"></i>';
    }
  }
```

So I tried to call this function inside an innerHtml attribute but it didn't work for some reason

```
<div [innerHTML]="icon(temps.currently.icon)"></div>
```

When I check the inspector the icons are rendered just not shown which made me believe it has something to do with the css and the icons because if I use innerHtml for an image or something else, it works just fine

Comment: don't use icon as function name. maybe a html5 key word.

Comment: Have you tried to adjust the `height` and `width` of the icons? Maybe put a class with that.

Comment: what you have in this? `temps.currently.icon`

Comment: check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-krpz1e

Comment: @JackLuo I tried to change it but still

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro The icons are working fine if I don't call them with a function inside innerHtml

Comment: @robert basically weather condition, rain, cloudy...

Comment: It works fine, something is wrong with your css class: Check this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/font-awesome-demo

Comment: @nircraft I thought the same but the css works fine if I use the icons directly without innerhtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers seem incomplete, so I'll add my own.

`[innerHtml]="icon('rain')"`

Consider what's happening in the template for the above statement. My guess is that double quotes in your class names are terminating the template string.

What you would end up with is `[innerHtml]="'<i class="icon-basecloud"></i><i class="icon-rainy"></i>"'`

This could evaluate to `"'<i class="` and already you have an illegal html string which cannot be rendered.

### So:

I would recommend moving your switch statement to the template itself.
Something like:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="temps.currently.icon">
    <span *ngSwitchCase="'rain'">
      <i class="icon-basecloud"></i><i class="icon-rainy"></i>
    </span>

    <span *ngSwitchCase="'cloudy'">
      <i class="icon-basecloud"></i><i class="icon-cloud"></i>
    </span>
    ... additional cases, etc
</div>
```

#### Update:

If you really wanted to clean this up more, you could abstract this switch statment to its own reusable component. That component could have an `@Input() iconString`, so to show multiple icons you just have multiple instance of the component. A Use-case could be something like:

```
<div>
  <span>Monday:<span>
  <weather-icon [iconString]="forecast['monday']"></weather-icon>
</div>

<div>
  <span>Tuesday:<span>
  <weather-icon [iconString]="forecast['tuesday']"></weather-icon>
</div>
```

Where you have a `forecast` variable in your component.ts

```
forecast = {
 monday: 'rain',
 tuesday: 'cloudy,
 ... etc
};
```

Comment: Thank you that worked fine, but I will have to use this method to display the icons for the weather in the following days, and with that solution the template will be just overloaded with switch statements. Is there another solution that can provide cleaner code?

Comment: I updated my answer with one optimization you can try.